# Proving equivalent statement for union - intersection and subset statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let A and B be sets. Show that the properties

(1) A ∪ B = B

(2) A ∩ B = A

(3) A ⊆ B

are equivalent conditions by

A) using an algebraic proof to show (1) implies (2)

B)using an element argument to show (2) implies (3)

C) using the method of your choice to prove (3) implies (1).

I was able to construct the following solution for C but I have no clue on the difference between algebraic or element argument proofs and I'm hoping for some help from you guys if possible

Answer (score 1):

An $\textit{element proof}$ could be the following. Since $A \cap B = A$,

$$x \in A \implies x \in A \cap B \implies x \in A \wedge x \in B \implies x \in B.$$

I suppose that an $\textit{algebraic proof}$ should involve some counting argument... So, let $A,B$ be $\textbf{finite}$ sets. We have already seen that $A \cap B \subseteq A$. If we show that

$$|A \cap B| = |A|,$$

then we are done (why?), but only since we are dealing with finite sets! (why?)

From the identity $$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$

we can conclude that $|A \cap B| = |A|$, since $|A \cup B| = |B|$ by hypothesis.